# Como manipular um elemento com jQuery quando eles estão no mesmo nível de hierarquia?

Tags: jquery

```
echo '<div class="servico">';
    ?><p class="servico_title opensans fw700 fs16"><?php the_title() ?></p><?php
    echo '<img src="'.UP.'/2015/08/enfeite_serv.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" class="enfeite_serv">';
    echo '<img src="'.UP.'/2015/08/arrow-down.jpg" class="chama_servico">';
    echo '<div class="servicos_the_content opensans fs14 fw400 white">'.content(18).'</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Quero através do `chama_servico` manipular `servicos_the_content`. Comecei mas não sei como terminar.

```
jQuery(function($){     

    $(".chama_servico").on('click', function(){

        var atributo = jQuery(this).parent('.servico') ...

    });

});
```

Eu vou colocar uma class `active` no `servicos_the_content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes subir no DOM até `.servico` e depois descer para `.servico_title`. Nesse caso usarias:

```
$(".chama_servico").on('click', function(){
    var atributo = $(this).closest('.servico').find('.servico_title').html();
});
```

Usei `.html()` como exemplo, para ir buscar o html desse lemento `p`.